# Can I use Java for building cross-platform mobile apps?

Tags: java, mobile, platform

I have read an article about Xamarin was buying RoboVM and enables developers to write mobile apps in Java for cross-platform. I am not sure if it is possible now to use Java for developing cross-platform mobile apps. Is there any reliable tools where I can write in Java for cross-platform mobile apps development? Is it a good choice to choose Java only for potential cross-platform mobile apps? I don't consider using C, C++, C# for that purpose since I have never been focusing on one of them. I apologize for the fans of those langauges. Or Is it a better choice that I better work with Java for Android apps and Swift for iOS apps? I plan to choose Java as a main language for all web apps, cross-platform mobile apps and robotic programming development.

Comment: Project Codename One is a Java based language which can compiled to native platform code to run on iPhone, Android and Blackberry; you'd need to verify Windows but it's probably there if not intended. Remember, you'll always behind the latest releases of the various OSs and not all the platforms support the same functionality (or do it the same way) which could present issues

Comment: I heard that Xamarin was (been) bought by Microsoft, so it's unlikely it will support Java

Answer (score 8):

I've been using [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) for quite a while now. Libgdx wasn't exactly an option as I'm not a game developer.

I played a bit with RoboVM before picking Codename One and it seems that it's more about Java for iOS and not about WORA (Write Once Run Anywhere). This might be a good choice for you if that's what you want but I prefer WORA. I tried the RoboVM FX bindings and they were just horribly broken in basic ways.

A few things I love about Codename One are:

1. Support - I have never used a product with such amazing free support. You get answers within a day at the latest and that really sealed the deal for me.
2. No need for a Mac - I use my Mac at home but in the office I need a PC.
3. Customization and familiarity - this is pretty much Swing but WAY better. Like we always wanted Swing to be as they put it...

The docs used to suck but they made a big push on it and it shows. Now if only they could fix the IntelliJ/IDEA plugin to the level of the NetBeans plugin I'd be golden!

Comment: Codename One is also fantastic!

I guess it really just depends on what you're trying to accomplish :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know they are not compatible with Java, but they claim that if you know Java you'll be fine with C#.

I found few interesting **weird** facts on their website about the transition... [source](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/xamarin-for-java/)

- In Java, you can pass parameters only by value, while in C# you can pass by reference as well as by value. (C# provides the `ref` and `out` keywords for passing parameters by reference; there is no equivalent to these in Java).
- In a Java `switch` statement, code can fall through into the next `case` section, but in C# the end of every `switch` section must terminate the `switch` (the end of each section must close with a `break` statement).
- ....

Comment: you realize that, in java while technically you always pass by value, but since you pass the reference of the object by value, it's more like a reference semantic than value semantic
that called call by sharing

Comment: I was pointing out how wrong their claims were, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK then, what's wrong with the summary of the switch statements?
Seems ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to write, [libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) might be a good solution.

You write your code once in java and it compiles to basically everything (even html5!)

You have to adhere to its coding conventions and use it's classes though. (Which are great for game development, not so much for other things... but you could still probably do whatever you want with it).